# Resizing Background Image next to div

Tags: html, css, background-image, responsive

I'm trying to make my front page responsive and really only have 2 elements to worry about. I have a background image starting from the left and a div containing various objects associated with the right side of the screen. I'd like to have it so that when the browser shrinks, the background image shrinks appropriately so that the div on the right side doesn't start intersecting with the image. As needed after a certain point I'm willing to make the background image disappear altogether so that the div has more space. How would I be able to do that? The code is very simple. Just a background image starting from the left and a div with right: 0%.

```css
body
{
    background-color: #EAE7DC;
    background-image: url("images/Earth.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.block1
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    top: 113px;
    min-width: 415px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
    <h1>Log In</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="button" onclick="logIn()">Log In</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share with us what you've tried? Maybe include your HTML/CSS?

Comment: Just uploaded the html and css. Thanks in advance. As for what I've tried, this is my first time trying to make a webpage responsive so I didn't really know where to start. I considered using viewport units but because the div on the right need to take up an absolute amount of space I couldn't do it that way. Ideally I'd like to subtract the div width from screen.width and give the remaining length to the background-image. But this would have to change on the fly when I change browser size so I can't call a javascript function to change it just once.

Comment: Have a look at docs for `background-size` [MDN - background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: Uhh, I'm not sure how this can help as I'm trying to appropriately resize the background image rather than move it around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your style:

```css
body
{
    background-color: #EAE7DC;
    background-image: url("images/Earth.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: calc(100vw - 430px) 100%;
}
```

The first expression in `background-size` is `width` and the second is `height`.
I used with [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) in order to get 100% of the viewport width (`vw`) minus the width of your block1

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is exactly what I've been looking for. I had no idea you could do something like calc in css.

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-size: cover;` to the body

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/OJRodLX

Comment: This seems to just cover my screen entirely and start intersecting with the div.

Answer (score 0):

Here is css code from w3schools, may help you!

`

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  }
      
  .bg {
  /* The image used */
   background-image: url("img_girl.jpg");
      
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
      
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the background disappear at some point what you can do is split your style according to the width of the screen using [Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) as follows:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body {
    // style that applies only when screen width is less than 400px
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 401px) {
  body {
    // style that applies only when screen width is more than 401px
  }
}
```